# How to replace a string to another string with webpack?

Tags: webpack

There are string holders everywhere in my code(.js, .ts... ), such as `'__DOMAIN_HOLDER__/id/20180101'`, and I want to replace `'__DOMAIN_HOLDER__'` to let say `'https://www.example.com'`.

How to accomplish this with webpack of latest version?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use webpack's DefinePlugin:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DOMAIN_HOLDER__: 'value'
})
```

and the variable will become available for you to use. Ofcourse, you would have to use it as a variable

```
`${__DOMAIN_HOLDER__}/id/20180101`
```

would be replaced with

```
value/id/20180101
```

Comment: Thank you! Is possible to achieve the same result with the same codebase using gulp?

Comment: This doesn't work on all strings but only globals. The docs are terrible on this.. it's very confusing.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of defining a global variable, you can instead use [`string-replace-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader)

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
          search: '__DOMAIN_HOLDER__',
          replace: 'https://www.example.com',
          flags: 'g'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I added "string-replace-loader": "^3.0.3", to my `package.json` to make this work - thanks.